# Data has same characters that I'm splitting it on

Tags: python

Sorry about the title, I'm a little unsure how to exactly ask this.

I have a dataset of game review information. The info is separated by commas, however some of the info, like titles or genres, have commas within them. These are all inside quotations. I want to convert this to a list but keep anything within quotes as a single index, rather than two. Here's an example. This is the raw data:

```
14,Amazing,Mark of the Ninja,PC,9.0,"Action, Adventure",Y,2012,9,7
```

I use `.rstrip().split(',')` to get:

```
[14, Amazing, Mark of the Ninga, PC, 9.0, "Action, Adventure", Y, 2012, 9, 7]
```

but `"Action, Adventure"` results in two indices. I want this as a single index, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I don't have too much experience with regular expressions but I'm guessing that's the solution I'm looking for.

Any suggestions on the best way to go about this problem?

Comment: Oh, looks like it's CSV (comma-separated values), which uses quotations to differentiate separator commas and content commas. The builtin [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module will parse this correctly: `list(csv.reader(["""14,Amazing,Mark of the Ninja,PC,9.0,"Action, Adventure",Y,2012,9,7"""]))`.

Comment: ***I have a dataset of game review information*** please share it. What's the source format? csv?

Comment: oh, thank you! it is a CSV, i didn't realize it stood for that. pretty obvious now lol. cheers mate

Comment: @PedroLobito sorry I didn't include the file extension, but I did example the exact format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The builtin [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module will handle this, with the only wrinkle being that that library is really designed to consume files, so the documentation may be a little unhelpful for your case, where you have a string. But the reader object can consume lists, so instead of a file, you can just pass in a list of CSV-formatted strings:

```
import csv
print(list(csv.reader(["""14,Amazing,Mark of the Ninja,PC,9.0,"Action, Adventure",Y,2012,9,7"""])))
# [['14', 'Amazing', 'Mark of the Ninja', 'PC', '9.0', 'Action, Adventure', 'Y', '2012', '9', '7']]
```

Comment: it actually is a file, almost 19000 lines. looking at the documentation for cvs.reader I'm a little confused why they also specify space as a delimiter. aren't the commas just the delimiter? i'm also a little confused about the quotechar parameter -- what is doing exactly?

Comment: CSV is a very crazy anti-standard—there are all kinds of dialects, including, as the documentation hints, ones with spaces as delimiters and perhaps `'` (single quote) as grouping quotations. The fact that using spaces as separators would make it a SSV file doesn't prevent the module from being called `csv`. (I personally frequently use TSV, tab-separated values, but I still use the `csv` module to parse those…)

Comment: okay, i get it now. i'm gonna just remember csv as "character separated values." i think that makes it a lot clearer to me